# Syntax highlighting in javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, syntax-highlighting

I have some code in a pre element in a UIWebView on iphone, so I'm looking for a javascript syntax highlighter that will detect the language automatically, like on SO you don't have to enter what language when you add to a post. I have looked at SyntaxHighlighter which seems the most used one, but doesn't seem to detect the language automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is what you want. I've used it before and it looks solid and useful.

(I'm positive that SO also uses this one.)